# How do I sort and display an array to create a leaderboards in unity C#

Tags: c#, php, sorting, unity-game-engine, leaderboard

I'm having a bit of a problem at the moment I have to work with a database with employees. these employes have different data these are strings and ints the example of what is in the array is: Naam:Pino | Team:2 | VerkoopA:12 | VerkoopB:12 | NPS:40 | conversie:10.

this is an example of only one employee there are more in the database and I already split them in the code. The thing I want to do is make a leaderboards out of this data however I do not know how to seperate the different items in the Array and if I have seperated this how can I sort the array to see who hase the most saleA and who has the most saleB so I can make this a leaderboard with a filter.

Also is there an easy way to have a visual leaderboards that can display a certain amount of employees? Because the way I displayed it now it shows nothing.

I'm using Unity and my own server with Xampp

With kind regards,

Dh

Script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class Leaderboard : MonoBehaviour
{

    // Array of all the employees
    public string[] leaderboard;

    Text txt;

    IEnumerator Start()
    {


        // Getting the leaderboard data from mySQL.
        WWW leaderboardsData = new WWW("http://localhost/leaderboards.php");
        yield return leaderboardsData;

        // Split every employee in the Array so they are all apart from each other. |
        // an example Message Naam:Pino | Team:2 | VerkoopA:12 | VerkoopB:12 | NPS:40 | Conversie:10 
        string leaderboardsDataString = leaderboardsData.text;
        leaderboard = leaderboardsDataString.Split(';');

        // for every employee in the array print every employee's data.
        foreach (string employee in leaderboard)
        {
            string employeeApart = employee;
            DisplayLeaderboards(employeeApart);
        }

    }

    // Display the leaderboards 1 by 1.
    void DisplayLeaderboards(string employeeApart)
    {
        print(employeeApart);

        txt = gameObject.GetComponent<Text>();
        txt.text = employeeApart;
    }



    string GetDataValue(string data, string index)
    {
        string value = data.Substring(data.IndexOf(index) + index.Length);
        if (value.Contains("|")) value = value.Remove(value.IndexOf("|"));
        return value;
    }

}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username =  "root";
$password = "";
$dbName = "test3";

//Make Connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbName);
//Check Connection
if(!$conn){
    die("Connection Failed. ". mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT ID, Team, VerkoopA, VerkoopB, NPS, Conversie FROM Leaderboards";
$result = mysqli_query($conn ,$sql);


if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
    //show data for each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo "ID:".$row['ID'] . "|Team:".$row['Team']. "|VerkoopA:".$row['VerkoopA']. "|VerkoopB:".$row['VerkoopB'] . "|NPS:".$row['NPS']. "|Conversie:".$row['Conversie'] . ";";
    }
}

?>
```

**EDIT:**

After programmers help, I decided to use json

I'm having a bit of a problem at the moment I have to work with a database with employees. these employes have different data the output of my PHP file is:

> [{"ID":"1","Team":"2","VerkoopA":"35","VerkoopB":"12","NPS":"25","Conversie":"18"},{"ID":"2","Team":"1","VerkoopA":"55","VerkoopB":"2","NPS":"12","Conversie":"40"},{"ID":"3","Team":"2","VerkoopA":"12","VerkoopB":"12","NPS":"40","Conversie":"10"}]

The thing I want to do is make a leaderboards out of this data however I do not know how to seperate the different items in the Array By using the JsonHelper I get an error: ArgumentException: JSON must represent an object

Script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class Leaderboard: MonoBehaviour
{
    // Array of all the employees

    [System.Serializable]
    public class LeaderBoard
    {
        public string ID;
        public string Team;
        public string VerkoopA;
        public string VerkoopB;
        public string NPS;
        public string Conversie;
    }



    Text txt;

    IEnumerator Start()
    {
        // Getting the leaderboard data from mySQL.
        WWW leaderboardsData = new WWW("http://localhost/leaderboards.php");
        yield return leaderboardsData;

        string leaderboardsDataString = leaderboardsData.text;

        print(leaderboardsDataString);
        LeaderBoard[] leaderboard;
        leaderboard = JsonHelper.FromJson<LeaderBoard>(leaderboardsDataString);

        // for every employee in the array print every employee's data.
        foreach (LeaderBoard employee in leaderboard)
        {
            DisplayLeaderboards(employee);
        }

    }


    // Display the leaderboards 1 by 1.
    void DisplayLeaderboards(LeaderBoard employeeApart)
    {
        Debug.Log("ID: " + employeeApart.ID);
        Debug.Log("Team: " + employeeApart.Team);
        Debug.Log("VerkoopA: " + employeeApart.VerkoopA);
        Debug.Log("VerkoopB: " + employeeApart.VerkoopB);
        Debug.Log("NPS: " + employeeApart.NPS);
        Debug.Log("Conversie: " + employeeApart.Conversie);
    }
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username =  "root";
$password = "";
$dbName = "test3";

//Make Connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbName);
//Check Connection
if(!$conn){
    die("Connection Failed. ". mysqli_connect_error());
}


$sql = "select * from Leaderboards";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($conn));

//create an array
$emparray = array();
while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $emparray[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($emparray);    
?>
```

Comment: You may be aware that GPG already has a complete leaderboard system. https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/leaderboards

Comment: well Im using this for a company with their own secured database and they have a lot of restrictions and secuirity, this is my local database to recreate in their space eventually. But thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have access to the server and the server script(php), you should do this with `json` or `xml` instead of separating the data with `|`.

Send the data from database as json. On Unity side, receive the data with `WWW` class then convert the json back to class with `JsonUtility`.

*Unity's `JsonUtility` does not support array so you will need a wrapper against it. You can get the `JsonHelper` class which allows json array [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36244111/3785314)*.

This is what I described above should look like:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class LeaderBoard
{
    public string ID;
    public string Team;
    public string VerkoopA;
    public string VerkoopB;
    public string NPS;
    public string Conversie;
}

Text txt;

IEnumerator _Start()
{


    // Getting the leaderboard data from mySQL.
    WWW leaderboardsData = new WWW("http://localhost/leaderboards.php");
    yield return leaderboardsData;


    string leaderboardsDataString = leaderboardsData.text;
    LeaderBoard[] leaderboard = JsonHelper.FromJson<LeaderBoard>(leaderboardsDataString);

    // for every employee in the array print every employee's data.
    foreach (LeaderBoard employee in leaderboard)
    {
        DisplayLeaderboards(employee);
    }

}

// Display the leaderboards 1 by 1.
void DisplayLeaderboards(LeaderBoard employeeApart)
{
    Debug.Log("ID: " + employeeApart.ID);
    Debug.Log("Team: " + employeeApart.Team);
    Debug.Log("VerkoopA: " + employeeApart.VerkoopA);
    Debug.Log("VerkoopB: " + employeeApart.VerkoopB);
    Debug.Log("NPS: " + employeeApart.NPS);
    Debug.Log("Conversie: " + employeeApart.Conversie);
}
```

On the php side, you have to use the `json_encode` function to encode your database information into json array before sending it to Unity. Not a php guy but you can learn more about that [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_php_example.htm) and [here](http://www.kodingmadesimple.com/2015/01/convert-mysql-to-json-using-php.html).

**Sorting the result**:

You can sort by `ID` after receiving the data from the server with

```
leaderboard = leaderboard.OrderBy(c => c.ID).ToArray();
```

or by `NPS`

```
leaderboard = leaderboard.OrderBy(c => c.NPS).ToArray();
```

This must be done before the `foreach` loop.

**EDIT:**

Your json generated by php cannot be ready directly in Unity. Not good at php and can't fix the json data on php side. Although, I can fix it on Unity side.

Add `{"Items":` in front of the received string then add `}` at the end of it.

I made a simple function for this:

```
string fixJson(string value)
{
    value = "{\"Items\":" + value + "}";
    return value;
}
```

Include that function to your script, then simply replace

```
string leaderboardsDataString = leaderboardsData.text;
```

with

```
string leaderboardsDataString = fixJson(leaderboardsData.text);
```

Everything should now work.

Comment: hey, thank you for your reply. I managed to get all the data correctly in Unity via PHP but when I try using the code to send it to the JsonHelper it gives me this error: 

ArgumentException: JSON must represent an object type

I have been trying to get it right but It didnt help.

Comment: Edit your question and add the the string you are getting from the server.

Comment: You are almost there. Scroll down to my answer where it says **EDIT** and continue reading from that. That should solve your problem. Don't forget to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) answer your problem is solved. I got it working on my side.

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped me a lot and it works. I was familiar with this site but never actually posted something myself but I'm glad I did thank you again.